# The Specified Compiler Compliance

Tags: anylogic

I use Anylogic University 8.7.6 and I found the following warning when opened an Anylogic model I've created before.

Description: The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 11 is used.

Should I do anything regarding this warning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your old project, it was specified that Java 8 was used. You can either change the Java AnyLogic should be using (not advised) in the settings in the screenshot below

[image]

Or you can safely ignore the warning and save your model.